# Cocos2d-x 3.13.1 crashes on iOS 64bit devices. Why can it be?

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I tested my game on mac osx desktop and it works correctly.

Whenever I try to play it on a 64bit devices, it crashes at random places (at one of the menu scenes.. it doesn't happen on the actual gameplay scene for example..) which are seemed to be related to multiple deallocations.. It crashes when I use Sprites and menuitems but I don't think that it is specific to a single thing... The cocos2d-x v3.13.1 code is untouched.

Why I think that it is related to 64bit?
I tested the game on iOS 10.2 and 10.1 on iPhone 6s Plus, iPad Pro1 and iPhone 5.
The game played PERFECTLY on iPhone 5 (which does not support arm64 but armv7).

Why can it be?

Here is the initial log lines (related to GL) for iPhone5 and iPhone 6s plus respectively:

```
2016-12-30 14:13:47.205163 mygame[443:20061] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful

{
  cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x-3.13.1
  cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
  cocos2d.x.build_type: DEBUG
  gl.supports_vertex_array_object: true
  cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
  gl.renderer: PowerVR SGX 543
  gl.vendor: Imagination Technologies
  gl.version: OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX543-128
  gl.max_texture_size: 4096
  gl.max_samples_allowed: 4
  gl.supports_S3TC: false
  gl.supports_ATITC: false
  gl.supports_ETC1: false
  gl.supports_OES_packed_depth_stencil: true
  gl.max_texture_units: 8
  gl.supports_PVRTC: true
  gl.supports_NPOT: true
  gl.supports_OES_map_buffer: true
  gl.supports_OES_depth24: true
  gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: true
  gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
}





//=======================

2016-12-30 14:12:28.310751 mygame[733:79376] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2016-12-30 14:12:28.702187 mygame[733:79273] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2016-12-30 14:12:28.703649 mygame[733:79273] Metal API Validation Enabled

{
  gl.supports_OES_map_buffer: true
  gl.supports_vertex_array_object: true
  cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x-3.13.1
  gl.vendor: Apple Inc.
  gl.supports_PVRTC: true
  gl.renderer: Apple A9 GPU
  cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
  gl.supports_S3TC: false
  gl.version: OpenGL ES 2.0 Metal - 38.3
  cocos2d.x.build_type: DEBUG
  gl.max_texture_size: 4096
  gl.supports_ETC1: false
  gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
  gl.max_texture_units: 8
  gl.max_samples_allowed: 4
  gl.supports_OES_packed_depth_stencil: true
  gl.supports_ATITC: false
  gl.supports_NPOT: true
  gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: true
  cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
  gl.supports_OES_depth24: true
}
```

**UPDATE:** I tested it on x64 (Mac OSX Desktop) and it works perfectly. So it is related to iOS 64 bit or... iOS Metal framework, etc...??